# Datetime Diff in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby application where i need to get date-time difference in Days-Hours-Minutes format. For this i m using following function

```
def duration  (from_time, to_time)
   from_time = from_time.to_time if from_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
   to_time = to_time.to_time if to_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
   distance_in_seconds = ((to_time - from_time).abs).round

   secs  = distance_in_seconds.to_int
   mins  = secs / 60
   hours = mins / 60
   days  = hours / 24

   if days > 0
     "#{days}d #{hours % 24}h"
   elsif hours > 0
     "#{hours}h #{mins % 60}m"
   elsif mins > 0
     "#{mins}m"
 end
end
```

The above called like this from another function

```
duration(aw_updated, Time.now)
```

But some time it gives me wrong result,

when i display above values

```
aw_updated is 2012-09-19 04:23:34 UTC
Time.now is   2012-09-19 16:33:09 +0530
Time.now.utc is 2012-09-19 11:03:09 UTC
```

And

```
Diff is 6h 26m
```

But my system time is 2012-09-19 16:33:09

Not sure where i m doing wrong , some UTC issue?

please advise

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your system time is showing UTC + 5.30

Comment: Diff should not be more than 12 hours?

Comment: The difference between 04:23:34 and 11:03:09 is 6h:39m:35s. Try running the code again and post the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For correct answer your both time should have same timezone `utc` in this case

So it is converting `2012-09-19 16:33:09 +0530` into `utc` which gives `2012-09-19 11:03:09 UTC` and hence difference is Diff is 6h 26m

Answer (score 0):

Would enter this as a comment but can't yet.

I haven't looked in detail at your function but do you have to build it from scratch? Why don't you use the Ruby in built [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) class. You can parse strings to DateTime objects, do the calculation and use the [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) method to output the time in a format that you want